# Seaborn Not Accepting Datetime value

Tags: python, seaborn

I have a data frame that has a `DateTime` column that I am trying to use for my plot visualization, but I am thrown an error when setting the column as my x-axis. I noticed in the documentation where `lineplot` accepts a number, not a datetime, but that seems strange to me as I have seen seaborn graphs with dates as the x-axis label. Is there something that I am doing wrong?

```
test_data = pd.read_csv('organic-sessions.csv', header=0, index_col='date', parse_dates=['date'])
test_data.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 730 entries, 2018-01-01 to 2019-12-31
Data columns (total 1 columns):
organic    274 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(1)
memory usage: 11.4 KB

sns.lineplot(x='date', y="organic", legend='full', data=test_data)

ValueError: Could not interpret input 'date'
```

Comment: `index_col='date',` means that `'date'` will be the dataframe's index. But if it is the index it's not a column in `test_data`; so seaborn cannot know which column you want to use. I guess the best test for yourself is: Can I print `test_data["date"]`? If not, forget about seaborn and make sure it's a column first

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest thank you for explanation. I see exactly what you mean and that was the issue